# How to know the "invisible" true width of a container?

Tags: apache-flex, width, clip

In Flex, I have a HBox that contains several elements. The container has clipContent set to true.

What I'd like to know, is what is the actual length of the remaining visual content that would be shown if the clipContant is set to false.

i.e: my HBox has 900 width, I addchild 5 elements, each of 200 width, I'd want to know how to retrieve the 100 that would complete the 200 x 5 total width.

Is there any property that could be used for this purpose?.

Comment: This may be inefficient but have you tried nesting an HBox inside your original Hbox so then you could just subtract the inside HBox from the outside one and get the difference you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah that could work, but I was expecting something more..  "native" if there is such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the children of the hbox and count the length of all its children.

```
var childLength:Number = 0;
for (var i:int = 0; i < myBox.numChildren; i++) {
    childLength += myBox.getChildAt(i).width;                   
}
var clippedLength:Number = childLength - myBox.width;
```

If you're using spark components use numElements and getElementAt(i) instead.